# Find the error in my workings for the proof of $\left(\frac{x}{x+2y} + \frac{y}{y+2z} + \frac{z}{z+2x}\right)\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Here are my workings...

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+2y} + \frac{y}{y+2z} + \frac{z}{z+2x}\right)\left( \frac{x+2y}{x} + \frac{y+2z}{y} + \frac{z+2x}{z}\right) ≥ (1+1+1)^2$$

$$\left(\frac{x}{x+2y} + \frac{y}{y+2z} + \frac{z}{z+2x}\right)(3+2(y/x + z/y + x/z))≥ 9 \tag{1}$$

However, by AM-GM,
$y/x + z/y + x/z ≥ 3,$ meaning that there is no maximum value for $y/x + z/y + x/z.$

Hence, $3+2(y/x + z/y + x/z)$ has no maximum value and we can't find the minimum value of $\left(\frac{x}{x+2y} + \frac{y}{y+2z} + \frac{z}{z+2x}\right)$ using equation $(1)$?

Please help me spot the error and enlighten me on what's the correct way to solve it (Using AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)

Comment: Instead of multiplying by $\sum \frac{x+2y}x$, if you use CS by multiplying with $\sum x(x+2y)$, nice things would happen... In using CS, choosing the right multiplier makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Yep I see! May I ask what's the thought process behind this? Is it noticing that (x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2yz + 2zx?

Comment: Yes, that makes it easier to spot. If it were to show $\sum \frac{x}{x+3y}\ge\frac34$ exactly similar approach would work, but would be less obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe,$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}}\frac{x}{x+2y}=\sum_{\text{cyclic}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+2xy}$$
Using [Titu's Lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/),
$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}}\frac{x^2}{x^2+2xy}\ge\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)}=1$$
$$\therefore\;\; \frac{x}{x+2y}+\frac{y}{y+2z}+\frac{z}{z+2x}\ge 1 $$

Comment: Titu's lemma is a form of Cauchy Schwarz Inequality. The link will give you a better idea.

Comment: Oh I just read it thanks! Is it possible for you to help me spot the error in my workings too?

Comment: $\sum \frac{x}{x+2y}$ and $\sum \frac{y}{x}$ are not independent of each other.

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now!